# Customization of the header of an article

Tags: moderncv, cv

How to reproduce this header's organisation not the font style:

[image]

I'm currently using this code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{moderncv}

\usepackage{babel}

\firstname{XXXX}
\familyname{XXXX}
\title{SDFPOIJD SDOFIJSDOI}              
\address{19 xxxxxx xx xxxx}{204545454 xxxx}    
\email{xxx@yahoo.fr}                      
\homepage{github.com/xxxx}
\mobile{xxxx xxxx xxx} 
\extrainfo{21 ans}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

How to deal with this please?

Comment: For the letter or the cv?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, for the cv .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `moderncv` you have to load a style file. The default style is named `classic`. However instead of redefine the default definition it's easier to define your own header. In such simple case you can use:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{babel}

\firstname{XXXX}
\familyname{XXXX}
\title{SDFPOIJD SDOFIJSDOI}              
\address{19 xxxxxx xx xxxx}{204545454 xxxx}    
\email{xxx@yahoo.fr}                      
\homepage{github.com/xxxx}
\phone{xxxx xxxx xxx} 
\extrainfo{21 ans}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\personaltitle{%
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
 \par\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
     \@firstname\ \@lastname \\
     \@addressstreet \\
     \@addresscity  \\
     Age:\ \@extrainfo \\
     \fixedphonesymbol:\ \collection@phones@item  \\
     E-mail:\ \emaillink{\@email} \\
     GitHub:\ \httplink{\@homepage} \\
 \end{tabular}\par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\personaltitle
\end{document}
```

Of course you can modify the font etc. for every element manually.

[image]